# How to call a python function through an ajax call in a django project?

Tags: django

I'm starting on a simple web app and I'm trying to call a python function to render a separate view via an ajax call. I want to click on the try button and render a different html template. Right now it just displays the error message from my ajax, but I have no idea what could possibly breaking it. I just need someone to point me in the right direction..some sort of a starting point would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

My project urls.py looks like this

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url, patterns
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from SudokuProject import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'', include('SudokuApp.urls', namespace="Sudoku"))) + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

My app urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'Home/', views.sudoku_home, name="home"),
    url(r'Solve/', views.sudoku_solve, name="solve")
]
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django_ajax.decorators import ajax

def sudoku_home(request):
    return render(request, 'SudokuHome.html')

@ajax
def sudoku_solve(request):
    return render(request, 'SudokuSolve.html')
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#try').click(function() {
        alert('hi');
        $.ajax({
            url:"{% url 'Sudoku:solve' %}",
            type:"POST",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('woohoo success');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("something's wrong");
            }
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<body>
    Hello Welcome to Sudoku
    <button id="try">try me</button>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}" ></script>
```

Comment: What error message do you get? Probably a csrftoken error?

Comment: I just get the alert I put in under error of ajax, "something's wrong"

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using [django-ajax](https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax) library, and you already installed it.

According to [django-ajax documentation](https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax), you have to return a dictionary:

> ```
> @ajax
> def my_view(request):
>     c = 2 + 3
>     return {'result': c}
>
> # The result is send to the browser in the following way (JSON format)
>
> {"status": 200, "statusText": "OK", "content": {"result": 5}}
> ```

So your function should return something like this:

```
@ajax
def sudoku_solve(request):
    return { "message": "hello world!" }
```

And you can use this data in your front-end as this:

```
...
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.content.message);
        },
...
```

Comment: Right, but my goal here isn't to send a string.. I want to render a completely different page, this has got to be possible in some way :/

Comment: @hotkoreanchick check documentation: https://github.com/yceruto/django-ajax#ajaxmixin-for-class-based-views

Comment: Hey, so I tried returning a simple string just like the one you posted, message , but I can't seem to ever hit success to be able to do anything with that returned data. Ajax always goes to error, any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to render the template and then send it back as a string, like this:

```
from django.template.loader import render_to_string

def sodoku_solve(request):
    html = render_to_string('SodukuSolve.html')
    return {'html': html}
```

On your client:

```
success: function(data) { alert(data.content.html); }
```

Comment: Tried, but didn't really work. It seems that my ajax is never successful. Even when I try returning a simple string , I can't seem to hit success. Any idea why?

Comment: Change your request type from POST to GET in your Ajax call